# promise & mocha: done() in before or not?

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js

I am reading [some tutorials on promise tests in mocha](https://gregjs.com/javascript/2015/asynchronous-tests-in-mocha-using-before-and-after-blocks/). There is a piece of codes:

```
before(function(done) {
  return Promise.resolve(save(article)).then(function() {
    done();
  });
});
```

Why `done()` called in the `then()` in the `before()`? What is the difference between the above codes and the following codes:

```
before(function(done) {
  return Promise.resolve(save(article));
});
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**

My question is to compare with the following codes:

```
before(function() {
  return Promise.resolve(save(article));
});
```

Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first code snippet with the `before` hook returns a promise *and* calls `done`. In Mocha 3.x and over, it will result in this error:

```
Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
```

It used to be that it did not particularly matter if you used `done` and returned a promise, but eventually the Mocha devs figured that specifying both `done` *and* returning a promise just meant the test designer made a mistake and it was better to have Mocha pitch a fit rather than silently allow it.

In your 2nd snippet, you have the `done` argument and return a promise but Mocha will still wait for `done` to be called and will timeout. (It really should detect the argument and raise an error like in the 1st case, but it doesn't...)

**Generally, if you are testing an asynchronous operation that produces a promise, it is simpler to return the promise than use `done`.** Here's an example illustrating the problem:

```
const assert = require("assert");

// This will result in a test timeout rather than give a nice error
// message.
it("something not tested properly", (done) => {
    Promise.resolve(1).then((x) => {
        assert.equal(x, 2);
        done();
    });
});

// Same test as before, but fixed to give you a good error message
// about expecting a value of 2. But look at the code you have to
// write to get Mocha to give you a nice error message.
it("something tested properly", (done) => {
    Promise.resolve(1).then((x) => {
        assert.equal(x, 2);
        done();
    }).catch(done);
});

// If you just return the promise, you can avoid having to pepper your
// code with catch closes and calls to done.
it("something tested properly but much simpler", () => {
    return Promise.resolve(1).then((x) => {
        assert.equal(x, 2);
    });
});
```

With regards to the completion of asynchronous operations, it works the same whether you are using `it`, `before`, `beforeEach`, `after` or `afterEach` so even though the example I gave is with `it`, the same applies to all the hooks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood 100% the question, but the tests will not start until `done` is called.

```
 beforeEach(function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      value = 0;
      done();
    }, 1);
  });
```

This test will not start until the done function is called in the call to beforeEach above. And this spec will not complete until its done is called.

```
  it("should support async execution of test preparation and expectations", function(done) {
    value++;
    expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    done();
  });
```

You don't have to pass done in your example, just:

```
before(function() {
  return Promise.resolve(save(article));
});
```

If you do pass `done` the test runner will expect to be called before continue, otherwise it will probably throw a timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case there is no functional difference. The callback, often called `done`, was introduced to handle asynchronous tests when using callbacks. Returning a `Promise` is sufficient, but note that you cannot define the `done` callback, because the test suite will wait until it's called. Use `done` when you can't easily return a `Promise`. In your case the second test will be infinite, because you define `done`, which you never actually call.