# mocha: how to make sure multiple async actions done before test run

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js

There are two async actions in the following codes: 1, this.OBJ.create, 2, this.OBJ.create will emit the event and this.callback should be called. Not all of them are promises, so `all` cannot be used. How to make sure that these two actions to be done before test.

```
describe('CREATE OBJ', function _test() {
  before(function(done) {
    this.callback = function(obj) {
      console.log('callback called.');
      this.obj = obj;
      done();
    }.bind(this);

    return this.OBJ.create(null, {})
        .bind(this)
        .then(function(obj) {
          this.obj = obj;
          console.log('this.obj created.');
        });
// this.OBJ.create will emit the event and this.callback should be called.
  });

  after(function() {
    console.log('this.obj.destroy() called.');
    return this.obj.destroy();
  });

  it('should run test', function() {
    console.log('test run.');
    ...
    console.log('test finished.');
  });
});
```

How about the following codes:

```
describe('CREATE OBJ', function _test() {
  before(function() {
    this.callback = function(obj) {
      console.log('callback called.');
      this.obj = obj;
    }.bind(this);
    return this.OBJ.create(null, {})
      .bind(this)
      .then(function(obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
        console.log('this.obj created.');
      })
      .delay(100);
    // this.OBJ.create will emit the event and this.callback should be called.
  });

  after(function() {
    console.log('this.obj.destroy() called.');
    return this.obj.destroy();
  });

  it('should run test', function() {
    console.log('test run.');
    ...
    console.log('test finished.');
  });
});
```

I am not sure about `done` and `return promise` in the `before`. Any comments welcomed. Thanks

**UPDATE**

I removed some codes to make my question to focus on `how to make sure multiple async actions done before test run`.

Some details:
1, OBJ is instance of EventEmitter. The callback will be called after event emitted.

2, this.OBJ already setup.

Comment: Your code is bizarre. Inside a hook Mocha binds `this` to a context object it provides. `this.OBJ` in your `before` hook should resolve to `undefined` because Mocha does not provide an `OBJ` field in the object is binds to `this`. Or you set `this.OBJ` but you're not showing how. It is furthermore unclear what should cause `this.callback` to be called. Mocha won't call it by itself. Unless (again) you've got some code somewhere that does that and you're not showing. And as explained [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45573072/1906307) using `done` and a promise together is not supported.

Comment: @Louis So in Mocha 3, my first piece of codes cannot run?

Comment: I tried, my first piece of code can run under mocha 3.4.2

Comment: in what environment do you run the tests? browser or node?