# Mocha tests requires a done() to conclude, but then says "Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both."

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, assert

Very annoying issue with a mocha test.

It hangs if I don't do anything, gives me

> Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

If do a `Promise.resolve(). And finally

> Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.

if I do `done()` in it's place.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

This is what my test looks like:

```js
it('test my middleware' function (done) {
  const req = MockRequest()
  const res = MockResponse()

  const next = (e) => {
    if (e) {
      return done()
    }
    try {
      assert.ok(somethingThatPasses())

      done()
    } catch (err) {
      done(err)
    }
  }

  myMiddleware(req, res, next)
})
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573072/promise-mocha-done-in-before-or-not

Comment: try to increase timeout
it('test my middleware' ,function (done) {
 this.timeout(15000);
  const req = MockRequest()...

Comment: None of those help unfortunately. I still timeout.

Comment: please copy paste all the code because it's unclear like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help anybody having the same issue, but I did finally get it to work by moving the `done()` outside of the callback, right after the call to `myMiddleware`.

Unfortunately I am still not 100% sure what the initial problem was.